# How to resolve Terraform module to correct repo

Tags: terraform

In golang, I'm building an application that will return info about any Terraform Public Registry module.  The application needs to see the files themselves. For instance, consider [this module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws/latest).  Version `3.8.2` will resolve to this git [repo and ref](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/tree/v3.8.2).

The user provides:

```
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version = "3.8.2"
```

And Terraform knows where to get the files.  Is there a public API (or other stable solution) that will allow code to map a module source/version to a repo+ref?

I'm using [go-getter](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-getter) to fetch the repo, so anything that produces go-getter [compatible source](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources) would also be welcome.

Comment: you use the api to get the source code repo programatically for a specific module or version https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/registry/api-docs#download-source-code-for-a-specific-module-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [terraform API](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/registry/api-docs#download-source-code-for-a-specific-module-version) to get the repo source of any given module. An example in bash might be

```bash
[almalinux@vps-f116ed9f ~]$ source="terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
[almalinux@vps-f116ed9f ~]$ version="3.8.2"
[almalinux@vps-f116ed9f ~]$ url=https://registry.terraform.io/v1/modules/${source}/${version}/download

[almalinux@vps-f116ed9f ~]$ curl -s -i $url | grep x-terraform-get | cut -f2- -d':'
 git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket?ref=v3.8.2
```

Also as noted in the docs the string may be go-getter comatible

> A successful response has no body, and includes the location from which the module version's source can be downloaded in the X-Terraform-Get header. Note that this string may contain special syntax interpreted by Terraform via go-getter. See the go-getter documentation for details.

Comment: You saved me from a bunch of useless work @ChrisDoyle. I was starting to reverse-engineer the [TF client](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/eed06e2342130d1c10f63bb846449d7ff63c0c40/internal/registry/client.go#L187)  :facepalm